# Reading a RasterIO MemoryFile triggers a GTiff driver warning/error message

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio

I have recently upgraded RasterIO from version 1.0.5 to 1.0.12. After this upgrade I now get `CPLE_NotSupported in driver GTiff does not support open option MODE` when reading a MemoryFile.

My code to write then read the memory file is

```
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile
with MemoryFile() as memfile:
    with memfile.open(**kwargs) as dst:
        dst.write_mask(clust_mask)
        dst.write(bands)

    with memfile.open() as src:
        for i, ea_band in enumerate(tmp_dst.read(masked=True)):
            print (ea_band.mean(), ea_band.std())
```

The kwargs used to create the file is

```
{'count': 2, 'crs': CRS({'init': u'epsg:28354'}), 'dtype': 'float32', 'driver': u'GTiff', 'transform': Affine(2.0, 0.0, 300146.0,
       0.0, -2.0, 6181978.0), 'height': 319, 'width': 358, 'nodata': -9999.0}
```

Is this and error or a warning and should I be worried about it? It seems to write/display the data correctly.
If it's just a warning how do I prevent it from being displayed?